# ¿Cómo ocultar desaparecer elemento con display de forma lenta?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Estoy haciendo una zona de registro y login, ya puse que al darle a un enlace(registrarse-¿Ya tengo cuenta?) la zona deseada aparezca y la otra desaparezca, esto lo logré con jquery. Ahora lo que quiero hacer es que al cambiar de sección este cambio se realice de forma lenta o con algún efecto para que no sea vea tan brusco el cambio, no sé si sea posible. De ante mano muchas gracias.

```js
$("#registrarse").click(function(){
  $("#conjunto").hide();
  $("#for").show();
  });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $("#ingresar").click(function(){
  $("#for").hide();
  $("#conjunto").show();
});
```

```css
#for {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="form-register" >
     <form class="" action="registers.php" method="post" id="for">
    <h4>Formulario Registro</h4>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="nombres" id="nombres" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre">
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Ingrese su Apellido">
    <input class="controls" type="email" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su Correo">
    <input class="controls" type="password" name="contraseña" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su Contraseña">
    <p>Estoy de acuerdo con <a href="#">Terminos y Condiciones</a></p>
    <input class="botons" type="submit" value="Registrar">
    <p><a href="#" id="ingresar">¿Ya tengo cuenta?</a></p>
      </form>

      <form class="" action="" method="" id="conjunto">
     <h4>Formulario Registro</h4>
     <input class="controls" type="email" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su Correo">
     <input class="controls" type="password" name="contraseña" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su Contraseña">
     <p>Estoy de acuerdo con <a href="#">Terminos y Condiciones</a></p>
     <input class="botons" type="submit" value="Registrar">
     <p><a href="#" id="registrarse">Registrarse</a></p>
       </form>
  </section>
```

Comment: .hide() o.show() aceptan parametros que es el tiempo ejemplo .hide(1000); .show(1000). Tenes otros efectos JQUERY.slideUP(), .slideUp(). .effect() 
https://jqueryui.com/effect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.hide() puede tener un parametro que indica el tiempo de *fade-out*. Lo mismo para .show() pero el tiempo es para el efecto *fade-in*.

En este caso, por ejemplo

```
$("#conjunto").hide(300); //300ms de fade-out
$("#for").show(500); // 500ms de fade-in
```

https://api.jquery.com/hide/
https://api.jquery.com/show/

Hay mas efectos de animacion que peudes encontrar en la documentacion:
https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

```js
$("#registrarse").click(function(){
  $("#conjunto").hide(500);
  $("#for").show(500);
  });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $("#ingresar").click(function(){
  $("#for").hide(500);
  $("#conjunto").show(500);
});
```

```css
#for {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="form-register" >
     <form class="" action="registers.php" method="post" id="for">
    <h4>Formulario Registro</h4>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="nombres" id="nombres" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre">
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Ingrese su Apellido">
    <input class="controls" type="email" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su Correo">
    <input class="controls" type="password" name="contraseña" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su Contraseña">
    <p>Estoy de acuerdo con <a href="#">Terminos y Condiciones</a></p>
    <input class="botons" type="submit" value="Registrar">
    <p><a href="#" id="ingresar">¿Ya tengo cuenta?</a></p>
      </form>

      <form class="" action="" method="" id="conjunto">
     <h4>Formulario Registro</h4>
     <input class="controls" type="email" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su Correo">
     <input class="controls" type="password" name="contraseña" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su Contraseña">
     <p>Estoy de acuerdo con <a href="#">Terminos y Condiciones</a></p>
     <input class="botons" type="submit" value="Registrar">
     <p><a href="#" id="registrarse">Registrarse</a></p>
       </form>
  </section>
```